# vue, svg onmove dragging not work correctly with a ViewBox

Tags: vue.js, svg, drag-and-drop, draggable, interact.js

I try to make a rectangle draggable. When I add a ViewBox to the svg the drag position is not correct anymore, without it works perfect. I think i need a scale factor. Have someone a solution?

Here is my example
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-interactjs-7t0nr

My drag logic

```
interact(o).draggable({
  onmove: event => {
    //let mouse = this.$parent.createSVGPoint();
    //console.log(mouse);
    //mouse.x = event.dx;
    //console.log(mouse.x);
    //mouse.y = event.dy;
    //mouse.matrixTransform(this.$parent.getScreenCTM());

    let index = event.target.attributes.index.value;
    this.points[index].x += event.dx;
    this.points[index].y += event.dy;
  }
});
```

**Update**

Found a solution with a scale factor; i have add this to my example

```
onmove: event => {
  let index = event.target.attributes.index.value;
  this.points[index].x += event.dx * this.scale;
  this.points[index].y += event.dy * this.scale;
}
```

```
mounted() {
  this.calculateScale();
  window.addEventListener("resize", this.calculateScale);
},
beforeDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener("resize", this.calculateScale);
},
methods: {
  calculateScale() {
    let rootRect = this.$refs.mainSvg.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.scale = this.svgWidth / rootRect.width;
    console.log(this.scale);
  }
}
```